# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'search-facet-city'"

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape the following website using Python 3, Selenium, and PhantomJS:

https://health.usnews.com/best-hospitals/search

I need to locate a search field and enter text into it, and then press enter to generate the search results. Below is the HTML that corresponds to the search field I am trying to locate:

```
<div class="search-field-view">

<div class="block-tight">
    <label class="" for="search-facet-city">
        <input id="search-facet-city" autocomplete="off" name="city" 
type="text" data-field-type="text" placeholder="City, State or ZIP" 
value="" />
    </label>
</div>

</div>
```

Below is my Python 3 code that attempts to locate this search field using the id "search-facet-city."

```
def scrape(self):
    url = 'https://health.usnews.com/best-hospitals/search'
    location = 'Massachusetts'

    # Instantiate the driver
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search-facet-city")
    elem.send_keys(self.location)

    driver.close()
```

I need to scrape some results from the page once the text is entered into the search field. However, I keep getting a NoSuchElementException error; it is not able to locate the search box element despite the fact that it exists. How can I fix this?

Comment: The error in your post title is looking for "search-facet-city" as a _class_, but your posted code looks for it as an _id_.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be id.

Comment: When I try fetching that url, I get a `403 Forbidden` response.  Are you sure you're able to read it?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to read the url. I'm able to scrape some text from the url, but my primary issue is locating the search box and entering text into it. I'm not quite sure what could be causing the 403 Forbidden response. Have you included all the requisite imports?

Comment: I'm getting the 403 from `wget` on the command line.  The website is probably disallowing robot-type clients.  I tried the url in chrome and the page loaded, however it completely froze my Mac when I tried to view source, so I don't think I'll be visiting the page again.

Comment: The only answer I can come up with is that the html code you gave at the top of your post isn't present in the page when it first loads; there must be some javascript which dynamically adds that code into the page when some action is performed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying. I think you were right about the website disallowing robot-type clients. I checked the robots.txt file and it disallows access to that search field box. It seems like I'll have to figure out another way to get search results for this site, perhaps by appending the state abbreviation to the original url.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


url = 'https://health.usnews.com/best-hospitals/search'
location = 'Massachusetts'
# Instantiate the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/pathTo/chromedriver')
#driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/pathTo/phantomjs')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.save_screenshot('out.png');
elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search-field-view']")))
span = elem.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='twitter-typeahead']")
input=span.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='tt-input' and @name='city']");
input.send_keys(location)
driver.save_screenshot('out2.png');
```

and it works.

But if I try with phantomJS, in `driver.save_screenshot('out.png');` I obtain:

[image]

As [@JonhGordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) said in the comments, the website make some checks. If you want to use phantomJS, you could try to change the `desired_capabilities` or the `service_args`.